# How to convert output to list to count it amount?

Tags: python, list

I wrote a script that parses a webpage and get the amount of links('a' tag) on it:

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
connection = urllib.urlopen('http://test.com')
dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'):
    print link
```

The output of a script:

```
./01.html
./52.html
./801.html
http://www.blablabla.com/1.html
#top
```

How can i convert it to list to count the amount of links? I use link.split() but it got to me:

```
['./01.html']
['./52.html']
['./801.html']
['http://www.blablabla.com/1.html']
['#top']
```

But i want to get:

`[./01.html, ./52.html, ./801.html, http://www.blablabla.com/1.html, #top]`

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... What result do you expect for the given example ? 5 ?

Comment: How about [len()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len)?

Comment: yep. the problem was in using split()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`link.split()` tries to split link itself. But you must work with entity that represents all links. In your case: `dom.xpath('//a/@href')`.

So this must help you:

```
links = list(dom.xpath('//a/@href'))
```

And getting length with a built-in `len` function:

```
print len(links)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list(dom.xpath('//a/@href'))
```

This will take the iterator that `dom.xpath` returns and puts every item into a list.